# How to disable display all posts from all categories?

Tags: plugins

I have multiple categories in my posts. I just want to display the first one "Animal Kingdom" by default, and remove "All" tab, is this possible? Because I have too many posts, the load speed is pretty slow. I can hide "All" tab, but it still shows all posts(from four categories). I tried to change the code in js_composer plugin, but it doesn't work. [The link of my website](https://lovenicoleart.me/?page_id=175&lang=en)

Thanks in advance!
[image]

the page looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Visual Composer

See documentation regarding Post Grid Element in Visual Composer. https://help.visualcomposer.com/docs/how-tos/how-to-add-category-filters-to-the-post-grid-elements/

### Block-based Themes

Instead of disabling unwanted categories, the standard approach is to select the category you want to display in a query loop block.

See this link from the documentation on how to filter by taxonomy https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/query-loop-block/#filters

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I tried the method you provided, but I don't have any block in these posts, they only consist of title and featured image, and I uploaded two images in my question, you can see the differences.

Comment: I assumed you are using a block theme. This is an easy way to insert query loop in your web page. Your theme is https://demo.curlythemes.com/art-gallery-wp/ and you are using this web builder https://wordpress.org/plugins/visualcomposer/.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I can't edit Post Grid since this feature requires paying visual compose premium, is there any other way to do this when using the free version of visual compose? I tried to change the source code of visual compose, but my changes didn't work.